# Multithreaded dll and lock whan calling function from second thread

Tags: c++, c, multithreading, debugging, dll

I have program which can use dll plugins. If program want to ask plugin for some decision, it will send message to the dll and wait for result.

Program also give dll, pointer to GetSymbol function. Using this function, dll can ask program for some symbols.

I have created some kind of dll proxy. If program send message to dll, dll send xmlrpc call to client and return results. Dll have also second thread which works as xmlrpc server. So client can send xmlrpc call to ask for symbol.

I found some interesting issue with that. And I have no idea what is wrong. When I use GetSymbol function from thread 1 everything work fine. But when I'm trying to use it from thread 2 Program locks... Is it possible? How Program can know which DLL thread called GetSymbol function?

[image: Scenario]

Comment: So your program actually gets the symbol, but when the `GetSymbols` method is called, then your program doesn't return? Are you using any kind of thread synchronization mechanisms in `GetSymbols` (i.e. locking, monitor, reset event, etc)?

Comment: "Program" is not my program, I'm only writing dll which "Program" use. It looks like I can call GetSymbol in dll but only in Thread 1, when I'm calling it from Thread 2 "Program" never return. In debugger I can see that it waits on some lock.

Comment: As far as I see it, it's not your problem... whoever wrote the program should make sure that the callback method works properly.

Comment: Thanks, but how it is possible that "Program" can discover which thread called GetSymbol? Maybe I can do some workaround for that?

Comment: I suspect "Program" uses a mutex to protect calls to it's internal bits.  This lock is probably owned/acquired by the application thread that initially calls `process_message`, but when you call `GetSymbol` on another thread, the new thread tries to acquire the mutex and it blocks.  I would imagine that you would need to implement some kind of messaging between the thread that called `process_message` and your xmlrpc thread in order to get the `process_message` thread to call `GetSymbol`.

Comment: @Adam, the problem is that `GetSymbol` seems to imply that you would get some sort of input from the user after they call `process_message`. A possible workaround would be to pass the symbol along with `process_message`. However, that may not be permissible, so in this case you're about the only person with enough knowledge to figure out how to pass the data without having the DLL callback to get it.

Answer (score 1):

A mutex possibly.

It is possible that the program holds a mutex while running into the dll. And the GetSymbol tries to lock the same mutex internally to secure some structs.

If the same thread tries to lock a mutex again, it will pass and increase a lock-count on the mutex. (reentrant mutex).

If thread2 calls the GetSymbol, it will actually wait for the mutex. And the 'Program' will also hold it because it waits for the process_message to complete first.